# IE can't see objects in .load DIV Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a form loading on a page that loads with an onclick event on the parent page using the following javascript. It gets loaded in a DIV.

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
 $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://myurl.co.nz/"+sourceURL+"");
}
```

Then on another on click event (within the new form) one of the fields in the form is populated with a random password.

```
<label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" onClick="genPwd()"/> 

function genPwd(){
$.post("rpc.php", {
    method: "genPwd"
     },
    function(data,textstatus){
    document.form.password.value = data.message;    
    }, "json");
}
```

All the javascript on the page is included at load time.

Chrome and FF are fine with this but IE8 says that document.form.password does not exist, I assume because it is not in the original page. Any way around this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `document.form` is deprecated. You could use this cross browser solution instead:

```
$('#passwordFieldId').val(data.message);
```

Comment: you can likely still get away with document.forms[idxOrName].elements[passwordFieldId].value = ...;

Comment: yes, probably document.forms[index] could work but provided you are already using jQuery it would be better to use its full power.